# like validation of fan page without permissions request

Tags: facebook, validation, permissions, facebook-like

I'm an web developer in Korea and I'm running a fan page on facebook.
and I create a iframe app in facebook. 
In this app, The only information I want to know is 
if the user liked the page.

So far, I used to do it with the signed request from facebook. 
But I Found this page which validate without permissions request

http://www.facebook.com/ITsamsung?sk=app_298897280155645

How is this validation done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php for this:

```
<?php

$signedRequestObject = parse_signed_request( $_POST["signed_request"],YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET );

if ($signedRequestObject["page"]){
    // this means this signed_request was generated on a page
    if ($signedRequestObject["page"]["liked"]){
        // the page was liked
    }
}


//used functions
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
  $sig = $this->base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode($this->base64_url_decode($payload), true);
  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    echo  'Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 : ';
    return false;
  }
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    echo = 'Bad Signed JSON signature!';
    return false;
  }
  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<fb:visible-to-connection>
    Here code for fans
</fb:visible-to-connection>
```

Answer (score 0):

facebook does not allow anymore. $signedRequestObject["page"]["liked"] is true if the loading user has liked the page, false if not. This field will no longer be included for any app created after the launch of v2.1 (August 7th, 2014), and will be permanently set to true for all other apps on November 5th, 2014.